# Java - ArrayList object looping through multiple values and keys

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, arraylist, dynamic

I'm new to Java and I'm making Following json by using a single arraylist with for loop and if statement.I want to use dynamic forloop.But I'm stuck with my for loop logic part.

Here is my java program.

**main.java**

```js
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;

public class SingleListForLoop {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws JsonProcessingException {

    List < Map < Object, Object >> dataProviderList = new LinkedList < > ();

    List < Object > yearList = new LinkedList < > ();

    yearList.add(2009);
    yearList.add(2010);
    yearList.add(2011);
    yearList.add(2012);
    yearList.add(2013);
    yearList.add(2014);

    yearList.add(21.4);
    yearList.add(31.3);
    yearList.add(15.6);
    yearList.add(34.8);
    yearList.add(20.1);
    yearList.add(27.3);

    yearList.add(20.3);
    yearList.add(43.1);
    yearList.add(19.8);
    yearList.add(34.7);
    yearList.add(24.4);
    yearList.add(21.9);

    for (int i = 0; i < (yearList.size() - (i + 6)); i++) {

      Map < Object, Object > dataProviderValueMap = new LinkedHashMap < > ();

      dataProviderValueMap.put("year", yearList.get(i));

      for (int j = i + 6; j <= (yearList.size() + (i - 12)); j++) {

        dataProviderValueMap.put("income", yearList.get(j));

        for (int k = 0; k <= (yearList.size() + (i - 6)); k++) {

          dataProviderValueMap.put("expenses", yearList.get(k));

          // for year 2014

          if (k == (yearList.size() - 1)) {

            dataProviderValueMap.put("dashLengthLine", 0);
            dataProviderValueMap.put("dashLengthColumn", 5);
            dataProviderValueMap.put("alpha", 0.5);
            dataProviderValueMap.put("additional", "(projection)");
          }

          // for year 2013
          if (k == (yearList.size() - 2)) {

            dataProviderValueMap.put("dashLengthLine", 5);
          }
        }
      }
      dataProviderList.add(dataProviderValueMap);
    }


    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

    String mapToJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(dataProviderList);
    System.out.println(mapToJson);

  }
}
```

I want following output:

**required output:**

```js
[ {
  "year" : 2009,
  "income" : 21.4,
  "expenses" : 20.3
}, {
  "year" : 2010,
  "income" : 31.3,
  "expenses" : 43.1
}, {
  "year" : 2011,
  "income" : 15.6,
  "expenses" : 19.8
}, {
  "year" : 2012,
  "income" : 34.8,
  "expenses" : 34.7
}, {
  "year" : 2013,
  "income" : 20.1,
  "expenses" : 24.4,
  "dashLengthLine" : 5
}, {
  "year" : 2014,
  "income" : 27.3,
  "expenses" : 21.9,
  "dashLengthLine" : 0,
  "dashLengthColumn" : 5,
  "alpha" : 0.5,
  "additional" : "(projection)"
} ]
```

How can i make this loop more concrete and enhanced for loop ?
i only want to use one arraylist and for loop with if statement having Map inside the for loop. thanks for the help!

Comment: Why are you using a single list that contains mixed data? That's really bad practice.

Comment: There is a possibility to have just one list if there is a requirement for that, but that must be a list of a structure of some kind. Probably an implementation of [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), as you have some required and some optional fields in the structure.

Comment: It doesn't actually prevent long coding, because it makes your list parsing loop code more complicated and hard to read and debug. Create a POJO that contains year, income and expense. Fill a list with such POJOs with the appropriate data. The resulting JSON will be trivial to create, without a map, even.